# How to move or resize to fit to certain plane?

Tags: transforms, snapping

I've took a model from web ([Plottergram from tinkercad.com](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/fxq3b3rsdHs-plottergram)) and wanted to modify it namely enlarge the table in one dimension. I did't need it to have rounded corners so it's enough to add a cube that fits table's width and height. In this very case I could do this in TinkerCAD itselft, but for some reason I was working offline, so I've got just .stl and Blender.

Now, to fit the width and height I just manually "carefully changed" dimensions of the created cube and then rounded the decimal number assuming the model has some reasonable dimensions. But I wonder if I can do this (resizing/moving) so that a plane of the box fits the corresponding plane of the existent detail in a simple way. Some editors use so-called "work plane" which can be attached to a plane of an object and then resizing/moving may behave in a "sticky" way in regard to it (such thing is in TinkerCAD, too); but it seems that there's no such tool in Blender (at least that is named work plane; this is according to a thread in some non-english forum). So, is there some convenient tool to do this?

PS the following image is added to comment the first answer:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do it with Snap to Mesh functionality in both Object and Edit mode (shift+tab), no need for any "work planes".

Here is the wiki page with a more precise description of the function:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh

Comment: that link is to version 2.4! A lot has changed since... https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html?highlight=snap

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful indeed, but I've got 2 issues regarding usage of transform snapping.

First, if I want to make a cube that has its top and bottom plane coinsiding with planes of another object, how do I do that? Either scaling or grabbing with snap to face allows me to get one plane correspondence, but when I try to make the other one coinside with that of the reference object, I get the first one changed (and vise versa).

Comment: Second, I've encountered a case where Blender thinks I want to snap the opposite face (right instead of left,
top instead of bottom). I've added a screenshot showing this case to the question: I want the brick to have a 
"shared plane" with another object, but Blender fits them so that the the two objects are on the opposite sides 
of the shared plane, while I want them to be on the same one.

How do I handle these two cases?

Comment: Is there an option to resize with one of the faces fixed (instead of fixed center)? That would solve both issues..

Comment: Yes, just move the 3D cursor to the vertex you desire and change the bounding box option to "center at cursor"